# Can be used only in preamble, \makeglossaries command

Tags: glossaries

I am running into the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 (Remove \makeglossaries
                            if you don't want any glossaries.)
?
```

Of course I need a glossary and I understand that I must call `\makeglossaries` before `\begin{document}`

Here is my main latex document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{morewrites}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage[linktocpage,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[clean,pdf,svgpath=../GraphiquesUML/]{svg}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{authoraftertitle}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{glossaires}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=C,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    %showframe,
    a4paper,
    body={160mm,245mm},
    left=25mm,top=25mm,
    headheight=10mm,headsep=5mm,
    footskip=10mm,
    marginparsep=0mm,
    marginparwidth=0mm
}

% Numérotation des paragraphes
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

% Début du document
\begin{document}

\clearpage

% Table des matières
\tableofcontents{}

\printglossaries

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Inside the `chapter_introduction.tex` file I have the `\printglossaries` command somewhere.

My `glossaires.tex` file contains this command:

```
\newglossaryentry{SaE}{
    name=SaE,
    description={Système à l'étude}
}
```

I don't understand why pdflatex complains about the `\makeglossaries` command.
Should I move it, or is there a package conflict ?

Thanks for your help

-- EDIT --
The glossaries package generate this warning in the log:

```
/home/.../specification.lof:
    1  
    2: Package glossaries Warning: No \printglossary or \printglossaries found.
    3: (Remove \makeglossaries if you don't want any glossaries.)
    4  This document will not have a glossary.
    5
```

Comment: My guess is, you need to put `\makeglossaries` after `\loadglentries`

Comment: Please reduce the non-compilable document to a compilable one. Those files used in `\input{...}` aren't available to us. Apart from that,  I can't see a reason why this should fail at all

Comment: Me neither... I removed the \input from the document, but not the \loadglentries. But I may remove it if you want.

Comment: @AMDG: I don't get your error

Comment: I just see in my log that the glossaries package doesn't find the \makeglossaries command. I edited the question.

Comment: @AMDG: I tried your 'new' file and the only warning I get is there is nothing to do -- you don't have a `\gls` or `\glsaddall` command in your file. If I use `\gls{SaE}` in the document body, the glossary is there

Comment: Yep, I tried to move all glossaries command in the main file, clean my project, rebuild, and move one by one the glossaries commands were they belong in my document. Now it is working. Weird.

However thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The missing `glossary` is due to a  missing `\gls{...}` or `\glsaddall` statement. As such, `glossaries` will not print anything.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{morewrites}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{eurosym}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[clean,pdf,svgpath=../GraphiquesUML/]{svg}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{authoraftertitle}

\usepackage[linktocpage,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{glossaires}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=C,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    %showframe,
    a4paper,
    body={160mm,245mm},
    left=25mm,top=25mm,
    headheight=10mm,headsep=5mm,
    footskip=10mm,
    marginparsep=0mm,
    marginparwidth=0mm
}

% Numérotation des paragraphes
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

% Début du document
\begin{document}

\clearpage

\gls{SaE}

% Table des matières
\tableofcontents{}

\printglossaries

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```